# How to show the same DIV container and different content based on the link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to have a hidden DIV that is displayed based on a link clicked in the table and it shows the associated information about that specific link click. A different link click should show that same table, however different information that is associated only with that link click.

I have tried utilizing some jquery. And everything works, as in showing the div and hiding content behind it. But it only shows the first content, not the second if I click the second link.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
    function() {
      $(".accept").click(function() {
        $(".hidden_div").show("slow");
        $("#link").hide("slow");
        $($this).show("slow");
      });

      $("#close_tab_button").click(function() {
        $(".hidden_div").hide("slow");
        $("#link").show("slow");
        $($this).hide("slow");

      });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="link" <p>Link Table and DIV</p><br>

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
      <table>
        <tr class="accept">
          <td><a href="#" value="link_1">Link 1</td>
       <td>Link 1 Description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accept">
       <td><a href="#" value="link_2">Link 2</td>
       <td>Link 2 Description</td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden_div">
     <div class="hidden_div_container">
      <div class="hidden_div_close"><div id="close_tab"><a href=""><img id="close_tab_button" src="../Media/close_button.png" width="20"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden_div_content">
    <div id="link_1"> blah blah blah</div>
    <div id="link_2"> blah blah blah blah</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You appear to have many problems with your attempt. `$($this)` should be `$(this)` and using that as a selector you will hide the close anchor and never display it again. I recommend you open the browser console so you can see the errors showing there. Here is an example after correcting your selector [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/52jqbnut/1/)

Comment: @NewToJS, something I have noticed is if I leave event.preventDefault();, it will have the close button, but if I close one div and click on another link, it never shows up again. If i remove that line, it shows up on each div, however all of the "information" shows...

Comment: Without having `event.preventDefault();` you will reload the page or send the client to the anchor `href` value.

Comment: what would be a way around this then?

Comment: I think the issue is that this $(this) reference is taking all of the links and showing them simultaneously. what i would like to happen is it only takes the value of that link and displays its associated information.

Answer (score 0):

@NewToJS 's fiddle seems to work, but if you want to display only the corresponding `div` to that link click. You should try

```
$(".accept").click(function() {
    $(".hidden_div").show("slow");
    $("#link").hide("slow");
    if($(this).hasClass("link_1")){
        $("#link_1").show("slow");
    }
    if($(this).hasClass("link_2")){
        $("#link_2").show("slow");
    }
});
```

And add classes to your link row like

```
<tr class="accept link_1">
<tr class="accept link_2">
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dLe58b6/6/)

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:** I changed `value` attribute of `anchor` to `name`, so it can be accessed in jQuery. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mjf9c46z/2/) when large number of options are present for links.

Comment: that would work. But it is going to be a table with 100 different options

Comment: In that case, you should get the value of child `anchor` element of the `clicked row`. Then use it to hide or show specific `div`

Comment: I still can't seem to get the code you posted to work. Two things I have noticed is that once you open any div, and close it, then try to open another, the close button disappears and doesn't return. Another thing I am seeing, is this only works if you have two div's hidden, I will have hundreds in this test. Without adding $("link_1".hide("slow"); hundreds of times and incrementing each one, how would i accomplish this?

Comment: I tested it again, when I click "Link 1" it shows "img(close button) Link 1 blah blah", then I click `close` and it returns to initial state and I can again open another `div` then close it the same way, and the button doesn't disappear in the fiddle, so I don't understand what do mean when you say that it disappears?. And about the second thing, you can simply use a class name to hide all divs like `$('.link_class').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a global object to put value:description.
Eg.

```
const data = [{link_1:'LINK 1 Description'},{link_2: 'LINK 2 Description'}];
```

When you click in row, with JS you get current link and other variable.

In your view, create a generic structure to show a Description and with JS, appendToHtml value

```
document.getElementById('#whatever').innetHTML = data.currentValue
```